# How can I make two container connect each other via serviceName in K8S?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I declared two containers in minikube cluster, `elasticsearch` and `kibana`. `kibana` needs to access elasticsearch endpoint at 9200 port. I declared `elasticsearch` as `StatefulSet` and give a serviceName `elasticsearch`.

When I look at kibana log I can see this error:

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-12-31T03:37:45Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","monitoring"],"pid":6,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-12-31T03:37:45Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","monitoring"],"pid":6,"message":"No living connections"}
```

it means kibana can't reach `elasticsearch` hostname. Is there anything wrong with my configuration?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: es-cluster
spec:
  serviceName: elasticsearch-entrypoint 
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: elasticsearch
          image: elasticsearch:7.10.1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9200
              name: rest
            - containerPort: 9300
              name: inter-node
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kibana
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: kibana
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: kibana
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: kibana
          image: kibana:7.10.1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5601
          env:
            - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS
              value: http://es-cluster-0.elasticsearch-entrypoint.default.svc.local:9200
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-entrypoint
  namespace: default
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    name: elasticsearch
  ports:
  - port: 9200
    name: rest
  - port: 9300
    name: inter-node
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kibana-entrypoint
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    name: kibana
  ports:
  - port: 5601
```

Comment: elasticsearch pods are up and running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a headless governing service for your statefulSet:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-entrypoint
  namespace: default
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    name: elasticsearch
  ports:
  - port: 9200
    name: rest
  - port: 9300
    name: inter-node
```

In your deployment of kibana env variable `ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS` need to set `http://es-cluster-0.elasticsearch-entrypoint.default.svc.cluster.local:9200`.

The template is like `my_pod_name.my_Service_Name.my_Namespace.svc.cluster-domain.example` , but you can skip the cluster-domain.example part. Only `Service_Name.Namespace.svc` will work fine.

here is the full yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: es-cluster
spec:
  serviceName:  elasticsearch-entrypoint
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: elasticsearch
          image: elasticsearch:7.10.1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9200
              name: rest
            - containerPort: 9300
              name: inter-node
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kibana
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: kibana
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: kibana
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: kibana
          image: kibana:7.10.1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5601
          env:
            - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS
              value: http://es-cluster-0.elasticsearch-entrypoint.default.svc.cluster.local:9200
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-entrypoint
  namespace: default
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    name: elasticsearch
  ports:
  - port: 9200
    name: rest
  - port: 9300
    name: inter-node
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kibana-entrypoint
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    name: kibana
  ports:
  - port: 5601
```

- [Ref](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#a-aaaa-records)

Comment: Do I need to use StatefulSet  for `elasticsearch`?

Comment: for database you should always use statefulset.

Comment: Why do you say that?

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao when you increase your replicas, the pods should have static names so that they can communicate each others.

Comment: Does it work for containers from different pod? I have updated the value in kibana but it still can't access the hostname.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao can you please update final working version of yaml. I tried running using Emon's update but it didn't work for

Comment: I updated the serviceName to be `elasticsearch-entrypoint`, but I still get this error: `Request error, retrying\nGET http://es-cluster-1.elasticsearch-entrypoint.default.svc.local:9200/_xpack => getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND es-cluster-1.elasticsearch-entrypoint.default.svc.local es-cluster-1.elasticsearch-entrypoint.default.svc.local:9200`

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao you need to update the service name in your statefulset  of elasticsearch from `serviceName: elasticsearch `  to  `serviceName:elasticsearch-entrypoint ` .  and also update `ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS` value to `http://es-cluster-0.elasticsearch-entrypoint.default.svc.local:9200`. is it working for you now?

Comment: I did that already. I updated the yaml file in the post. I still see this error: `Request error, retrying\nGET http://es-cluster-0.elasticsearch-entrypoint.default.svc.local:9200/_xpack => getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND es-cluster-0.elasticsearch-entrypoint.default.svc.local es-cluster-0.elasticsearch-entrypoint.default.svc.local:9200`

Comment: can you show me the output for `kubectl get endpoints elasticsearch-entrypoint`?

Comment: can you please check with the full yaml? i have added it in my answer. i have notice another error. can you please update   `ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS`  with  `http://es-cluster-0.elasticsearch-entrypoint.default.svc.cluster.local:9200`

Comment: Where does the `-0` of `es-cluster-0` come from?

Comment: @VictorWong here he is using headless service for statefulset. so the specific pod's  `dns name` template will look like this `my_pod_name.my_service_name.my_namespace.svc.cluster.local` 
[Ref](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-network-id)

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#limitations)

StatefulSets currently require a Headless Service to be responsible for the network identity of the Pods. You are responsible for creating this service by specifying `clusterIP: None`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  namespace: default
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    name: elasticsearch
  ports:
  - port: 9200
  - port: 9300
```

Then you can access it via `elasticsearch:9200` and `elasticsearch:9300`